# Searching for a question addressing the tor behind the scenes

Tags: discussion

Has there been any question asked about how tor is working behind the scenes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The [search page](https://tor.stackexchange.com/search) helps you to find questions, but currently I'm not sure what you're looking for.